# Array of bytes pointers in i2c

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, arduino

I've saved the data arriving trough i2c in an array and I would like to access the single values. When I save and print the array values from the function saving them the values are fine, when I try to access them from outside that function I get a "double" value meaning that in the array there is a value "0" memorized before every valued I saved.

```
int byteArray[100];
boolean hoRicevutoDati = false;


void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600); // start serial for output
 Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);  
 Wire.onReceive(receiveDataList);
}

void loop() {
 delay(1000);
 hoRicevutoDati = dalleNoteAlMotorino(hoRicevutoDati);
}

void receiveDataList(int numByte){
 int i = 0;
 while(Wire.available() > 0){
  for(i=0; i < 100; i++){
    byteArray[i] = Wire.read();
    if (byteArray[i] == 255){
      break;
      }
    else{
      Serial.println(byteArray[i]);
      i++;
    }
  };
 }

boolean dalleNoteAlMotorino (boolean hoRicevutoDati) {
 while (hoRicevutoDati == true) {
  Serial.print("byte[0] ");
  Serial.println(byteArray[0]);
  Serial.print("byte[1] ");
  Serial.println(byteArray[1]);
  Serial.print("byte[2] ");
  Serial.println(byteArray[2]);
  Serial.print("byte[3] ");
  Serial.println(byteArray[3]);
  Serial.print("byte[4] ");
  Serial.println(byteArray[4]);
  return hoRicevutoDati = false;
 }
}
```

via i2c I'm transmitting {0,2,5,4,...}, when dalleNoteAlMotorino runs I'm expecting to see 0, 2, 5, 4... instead I get 0 0 0 2 0 5 0 4... every number has a 0 before. Looking around I think I might have turned the byte array into an array of pointers though I'm not sure how I did it since I'm not passing the array as parameter anywhere. I also don't understand what exactly is that 0 before the value or how can I access just the value. Basically I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Arduino is not C! However told you does not know the C language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving here this in case someone else had my problem. I used

```
 Serial.print("value ");
 Serial.println(byteArray[i]);
 Serial.print("pointer address");
 Serial.println((int)&byteArray[i]);
```

to check on the pointer adresses and I saw that the values from i2c got memorized every 4bytes while my function searched for them every 2 bytes. From what I understand C (and arduino) let you use a variable number to memorize int and I think that was the problem.